# Is there a reason to use String Literals now that there's string based enums in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Assuming that I have the compiler option noImplicitReturn turned ON, if I have this code:

```
enum ListA {
    option1 = "opt1",
    option2 = "opt2",
    option3 = "opt3"
}

type ListB = "opt1" | "opt2" | "opt3";

function transformA(x: ListA): number {
    switch (x) {
        case ListA.option1:
            return 1;
        case ListA.option2:
            return 2;
    }
}

function transformB(x: ListB): number {
    switch (x) {
        case "opt1":
            return 1;
        case "opt2":
            return 2;
    }
}
```

Both cases seem to work in a similar way, they're both considered discriminated unions and are exhaustively checked.

The compiler throws errors for both functions transformA and transformB because they both don't handle all possible cases.

[Code in playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20ListA%20%7B%0D%0A%09option1%20%3D%20%22opt1%22%2C%0D%0A%09option2%20%3D%20%22opt2%22%2C%0D%0A%09option3%20%3D%20%22opt3%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ListB%20%3D%20%22opt1%22%20%7C%20%22opt2%22%20%7C%20%22opt3%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20transformA(x%3A%20ListA)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09switch%20(x)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09case%20ListA.option1%3A%0D%0A%09%09%09return%201%3B%0D%0A%09%09case%20ListA.option2%3A%0D%0A%09%09%09return%202%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20transformB(x%3A%20ListB)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09switch%20(x)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09case%20%22opt1%22%3A%0D%0A%09%09%09return%201%3B%0D%0A%09%09case%20%22opt2%22%3A%0D%0A%09%09%09return%202%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)

So is there a reason to use string literals now? Or is just a matter of taste?

I tend to prefer the enum in this case because it would make the refactoring easier in case that the possible values change.

Answer (score 0):

One reason would be if you don't have just string values, for example :

```
function test (p: "yes" | "no" | true | false | 1 | 0)  {
}
```

Comment: but then this is not a string literal anymore, it's a union type of different types.

Comment: I was pointing out that you can use string literal types in ways you can't use string enums. With string enums you are limited to just strings, with literal types you can mix them with other literal value types and get interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problematic question and could be better answered at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

The use case you describe in your post to replace string literals with an enum is more solid in this example and, like you've said, easier when refactoring is needed. However, using string literals is still good practice when, for instance, considering the usage of the `keyof` keyword to allow passing trough all known keys of a type or an object (in conjunction with `typeof`) as valid arguments. I find myself using `mapped types` a lot since it does not create a new object when compiled where the main concern is the usage of type-guarding arguments.

Comment: You're probably right I'll ask this on software recommendations, but the use of keyof is not the same as creating a string literal type by hand, in this case, you're creating a type dynamically.

Comment: @vintem What I explicitly answered was `So is there a reason to use string literals now? Or is just a matter of taste?`, in which my answer to that is **yes**. If your question pointed to the usage as described in your post, I would agree with you that the usage of enums and the like are more sophisticated.